# Tibco Ems start up error

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-topic

I am trying to start **EMS Server (version-5.0)**

[image]

in unix
i am getting below error and i am tracing logs but i dont see any data in log file also its printing same logs.

```
-bash-3.2$  /TIBCO/installs/ems/5.0/bin/tibemsd -config /TIBCO/installs/ems/5.0/bin/tibemsd-db.conf

TIBCO Enterprise Message Service.
Copyright 2003-2008 by TIBCO Software Inc.
All rights reserved.

Version 5.0.0 V28 4/29/2008

2016-01-28 03:28:38.531 Process started from '/TIBCO/installs/ems/5.0/bin/tibemsd'.
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Process Id: 21959
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Hostname: lxtibqaapp3
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Hostname IP address: 10.32.12.146
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Detected IP interface: 127.0.0.1 (lo)
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Detected IP interface: 10.32.12.146 (bond0)
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Detected IP interface: 10.35.3.22 (bond1)
2016-01-28 03:28:38.532 Reading configuration from '/TIBCO/installs/ems/5.0/bin/tibemsd-db.conf'.
2016-01-28 03:28:38.533 Logging into file '/TIBCO/installs/ems/5.0/logs/EMS_QAAPP3.log'
2016-01-28 03:28:38.721 FATAL: Exception in startup, exiting.
```

Please any one give suggestion on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the configuration file being used the right one? Usually, it is named `tibemsd.conf`. Did you try looking at log file?

Comment: hi yes its right file we are renamed as tibemsd-db.conf

in log file also i can see same error i did not found any more clues on this any help please let me know

Comment: Ok, then what is there in log file? See if you can find any leads to find the cause and rectify?

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the right listen IP address in the tibemsd.conf file? If the server doesn't own the IP it won't start.

Comment: this is more of a tip than an answer, and is better left as a comment